# how to refresh the display of a DragTarget Widget

Tags: dart, flutter-web

Initially my 'TRY' pockets are empty and display thus:
[Empty pockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVp0D.png)
The pockets are then filled by the user dragging counters into them. Once all the pockets are filled e.g.
[Filled pockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WyFN.png)
they are then processed and the pockets can then be emptied and should be redisplayed. And that is the problem: the counters are still showing.

Here is the code for the DragTarget:

```
/// Drag Target --------

class CatcherPocket extends StatefulWidget {
  final int position;
  int colourID;
  Color colour;
  CatcherPocket(
      {Key? key,
      required this.position,
      required this.colourID,
      required this.colour})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CatcherPocket> createState() {
    // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
    return CatcherPocketState(
        position: position, colourID: colourID, colour: colour);
  }
}

class CatcherPocketState extends State<CatcherPocket> {
  final int position;
  int colourID;
  Color colour;
  CatcherPocketState(
      {required this.position, required this.colourID, required this.colour});

  @override
  DragTarget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DragTarget<CounterItem>(
      builder: (context, candidateItems, rejectedItems) {
        return Pocket(colourID: colourID, colour: colour);
      },
      onAccept: (ci) {
        setState(() {
          colourID = ci.uid;
          colour = ci.imageProvider.colour;
        });
        GameState.updateTry(position, colourID, colour);
      },
    );
  }
}

// ---------------- END OF Draggable counter stuff ------------------
```

I populate a list of pocket handles when they are initially built and use these to reset their internal state using the following code:

```
  static List<CatcherPocket> cps = []; // to be populated on initilization

  static resetTryCounters() {
    for (CatcherPocket cp in cps) {
      cp.colour = DDDtheme.standard.primaryColor;
      cp.colourID = -1;
    }
  }
```

After invoking a 'setState' in the root ancestor Widget I would expect it to redraw the pockets in this reset state but it doesn't.

Any ideas why and a fix would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After some days of not thinking about it, the solution came to me. But it is crude and I am sure a more elegant solution is possible. Basically it involves changing the state of the CatcherPockets externally.

I modified the CatcherPocket to keep a handle (the 'cps' variable) to its state:

```
class CatcherPocket extends StatefulWidget {
  final int position;
  int colourID;
  Color colour;
  late CatcherPocketState cps = CatcherPocketState(
      position: position, colourID: colourID, colour: colour);
  CatcherPocket(
      {Key? key,
      required this.position,
      required this.colourID,
      required this.colour})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CatcherPocket> createState() {
    // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
    return cps;
  }
}
```

This enabled a modified 'resetTryCounters' to get at the CatcherPocketState thus:

```
  static List<CatcherPocket> cpockets = [];

  static resetTryCounters() {
    for (CatcherPocket cp in cpockets) {
      cp.colour = DDDtheme.standard.primaryColor;
      cp.colourID = -1;
      if (cp.cps.mounted) {
        cp.cps.colour = DDDtheme.standard.primaryColor;
        cp.cps.colourID = -1;
        cp.cps.setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }
```

It works, but it blows the idea of *encapsulation* out of the water. Also, I wonder if there is a better way of passing the initialization parms for CatcherPocket to its State.